# double cannot be derefernenced when doing an if (answer.isEmpty())

Tags: java, double

Here's my code:

```
package logarithm;

import javax.swing.*;


public class Logarithm
{

    private static int i;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        // TODO code application logic here

        do
        {
            double answer = new Double(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the end result?"));

            if (answer.isEmpty())
            {
                JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the starting number?");
            }
            double start = new Double(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the starting number?"));

            double step = new Double(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How big are the steps?"));

            double mid = answer / start;

            double algerithm1 = Math.log10(mid);
            double algerithm2 = Math.log10(step);

            double var = algerithm1 / algerithm2;


            if (Double.isNaN(var))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The're is an error! You filled in a zero!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                i = 1;
            } else if (Double.isInfinite(var))
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The number is infinite!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                i = 1;
            } else
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "And the variable is " + var + ".", "variable", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);


            if (i == 1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Restarting!", "Restarting", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }

            int reply = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Try again?", "Restart", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

            if (reply == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION)
            {
                i = 1;
            } else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Thanks for using my program!", "Goobye", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        } while (i == 1);
    }
}
```

I am getting an error at `if (answer.isEmpty())` Please help me!

I am new to coding

Comment: Why do you think you can call a method on `double`? And what is `isEmpty` supposed to do there?

Comment: @Tom Also, the `Double` class doesn't have a `isEmpty`, so it doesn't work either way

Comment: I want to see if its empty. The text below that is placeholder.

Comment: A number can't be empty.

Comment: @Tom What can I do to get it check if its empty?

Comment: @Tom I want to know if something is inputted. I don't want people to click the Cancel and then leave it empty.

Comment: @Shashwat Can you help me?

Comment: That dialog window returns a string! Check on that BEFORE turning the string into a number!

Answer (score 1):

Try checking before if the `String` is valid. You could do

```
String s = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What is the end result?");
if(s.isEmpty()){
    //Error String is Empty
}else{
    double d = Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

Comment: That gives an error leter on the in te script becuase it tries to devide string with double.

Comment: And does this make me able to go into like 0.004879489 numbers?

Comment: @TheRedTurtlez did you make a `double` out of the `String` ? .

Comment: No? I don't know. Changing it to string doesnt work becuase you cunt use strings to devide.

Comment: @TheRedTurtlez check my updated code. It has `d` as the `double`. Now you can use it as a `double`

Comment: I suggest using `Double.parseDouble(s)` instead.

Comment: @TheRedTurtlez that means you are still doing something wrong. If you want more specific help you will have to explain what you mean by not working.

Comment: It gives me error. This is the first program im making.

Comment: @TheRedTurtlez would be better if you could specify the error. Also, try updating the code in the question